# self=this weird behavior in nested viewmodel with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get to grips with knockout.js, but I seem to be running into a javascript quirck I am not aware of.

#### Html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: someList">
    <li data-bind="text: number"></li>
</ul>
```

#### Javascript

```
function NestedViewModel(number) {
    self = this;
    self.number = ko.observable(number); 
}

function ViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.someList = [];

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        var vm = new NestedViewModel(i);
        self.someList.push(vm);
    }

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. The console shows an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

When I remove the self = this; line from the NestedViewModel, and I replace self.number by this.number, everything works fine! I have no clue what javascript is doing under the hood here... Does somebody have an explanation for this? And a solution?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkokorian/z9xdkvcv/2/)

Comment: For a morde detailed explanation about `this`, please have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare those variables by putting `var` in front of them. Without declaring them, you're trying to write to the global `self`, which most browsers won't let you do. (If it weren't that there's already a global called `self` in browsers, that code would be falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and would still want `var` — in fact, it does later, with `i`.)

E.g.:

```
function NestedViewModel(number) {
    var self = this;
//  ^^^
    self.number = ko.observable(number); 
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
//  ^^^
    self.someList = [];

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
//       ^^^
        var vm = new NestedViewModel(i);
        self.someList.push(vm);
    }

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

---

(Mind you, there's no need for a `self` variable in the quoted code, but I'm assuming at some point you use a closure and the `self` becomes useful then.)

---

It wouldn't have helped with `self`, but you might want to consider using strict mode, which would have warned you about the undeclared `i` variable. You do that by putting `"use strict"` at the top of the script file; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it).

Comment: Aarrrg! It seems really obvious now. I'm just too used to using typesafe languages so I don't notice these mistakes right away. Hopefully "use strict" is going to solve that, at least partly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @T.J. You will probably want to make the array an observable too...

```
self.someList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Comment: You're right, but it's nice to be aware that the option is there, perhaps I should have added it as a comment

Comment: Indeed, I simplified the example code down to the bare essentials to demonstrate the problem:)